# Does every topological group embed as a closed subgroup in an amenable group?

Tags: gr.group-theory, topological-groups, amenability

It is a standard result that closed subgroups of locally compact amenable groups are themselves amenable, so for example $F_2$, the free group on two generators, cannot be embedded as a closed subgroup of a locally compact amenable group. However, by a result of Pestov, $F_2$ embeds as a closed subgroup of $\mathrm{Aut}(\Bbb Q,\leq)$ and the latter group is (extremely) amenable.

Are there topological groups that cannot be embedded as a closed subgroup of any amenable group?

Comment: It would already be interesting for Polish groups.

Comment: @YCor indeed Polish groups are the case I'm most interested in, but maybe something can be said in general

Comment: Note that in the larger generality, an embedding with closed image need not be a homeomorphism onto its image (or it's implicit in "embedding").

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At least for Polish groups, which was the case I was most interested in, the answer is positive.

I mentioned this question to Ola Kwiatkowska yesterday and she immediately pointed out that one of the standard universal Polish groups, the group $\mathrm{Iso}(\Bbb U)$ of isometries of the Urysohn space, is in fact not only amenable, but even extremely amenable (and Polish subgroups of Polish groups are closed).

For arbitrary groups I still expect the answer to be positive, but I have no meaningful comments to make about that case, apart from the fact that if a group embeds as a closed subgroup into an amenable group $G$, then it also embeds as a closed subgroup into an extremely amenable group, namely $L^0(G,X,\mu)$.

**Edit (13/03/2024):**

It is indeed true that every topological group embeds as a topological subgroup into an (extremely) amenable group, this follows from a generalization of the argument for Polish groups mentioned above. Uspenskij proved (see Theorem 1.7 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004119)) that for every topological group $G$ there exists a "generalized Urysohn space" $U$ such that $G$ is isomorphic to a subgroup of $\mathrm{Iso}(U)$, while Pestov proved (see Theorem 6.6 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0004010)) that $\mathrm{Iso}(U)$ is extremely amenable for all those generalized Urysohn spaces (see also Corollary 6.7 and 6.8 in Pestov's paper).